# How to assign when value can have multiple types?

Tags: typescript, apexcharts

I would write this:

```
_heatMap[i].data[j].y = y + 1
```

Got this error:

```
Property 'y' does not exist on type 'number | number[] | { x: any; y: any; fill?: ApexFill; fillColor?: string; strokeColor?: string; meta?: any; goals?: any; barHeightOffset?: number; columnWidthOffset?: number; } | [number, number] | [...]'.
  Property 'y' does not exist on type 'number'.
```

Yes, `y` could be `number` or `number[]`, but it is not. In my case it is the object: `{ x: any; y: any; fill?: ApexFill; fillColor?: string; strokeColor?: string; meta?: any; goals?: any; barHeightOffset?: number; columnWidthOffset?: number; }`

And I need the `y` from it.

How can I assign it?

This is an example of the data:

```json
[
    {
      name: "Series 1",
      data: [{
        x: 'W1',
        y: 22
      }, {
        x: 'W2',
        y: 29
      }, {
        x: 'W3',
        y: 13
      }, {
        x: 'W4',
        y: 32
      }]
    },
```

Anyway ApexChart is used here: https://apexcharts.com/docs/chart-types/heatmap-chart/

```js
type ApexAxisChartSeries = {
  name?: string
  type?: string
  color?: string
  data:
    | (number | null)[]
    | {
        x: any;
        y: any;
        fill?: ApexFill;
        fillColor?: string;
        strokeColor?: string;
        meta?: any;
        goals?: any;
        barHeightOffset?: number;
        columnWidthOffset?: number;
      }[]
    | [number, number | null][]
    | [number, (number | null)[]][]
    | number[][];
}[]
```

Comment: How is the type from _heatMap declared (or assigned)? Can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), a typescript playground link would be nice. However my initial suspicion is that the new TS4.9 feature [`satisfies`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#the-satisfies-operator) should work for you. Otherwise you'll have to use a type-guard to ensure this is narrowed correctly, something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WK9ODN).

Comment: `_heatMap` has a `ApexAxisChartSeries` type, added to the question

Answer (score 0):

Going off of the types declared by https://github.com/apexcharts/apexcharts.js/blob/main/types/apexcharts.d.ts there are several ways you can do this, dependent on how you are retrieving the data.

For most methods you'll have to create a custom type which is just the narrowed type, we'll use a couple of [utility types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html) to accomplish this:

```js
type ApexAxisChartSeriesWithDataObject = (Omit<ApexAxisChartSeries[number], 'data'> & {
  // the reason we use {x: any} instead of {}, is because arrays are objects too
  data: Extract<ApexAxisChartSeries[number]['data'][number], {x: any}>[]
})[]
```

### `satisfies`

If you are declaring the data as a `const` in your `.ts` file the simplest way to do this is with [`satisfies`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#the-satisfies-operator). Notably this doesn't require the custom type above.

```js
const satisified = [
    {
      name: "Series 1",
      data: [{
        x: 'W1',
        y: 22
      }, {
        x: 'W2',
        y: 29
      }, {
        x: 'W3',
        y: 13
      }, {
        x: 'W4',
        y: 32
      }]
    }
] satisfies ApexAxisChartSeries

satisified[0]['data'][0]['x'] += 1
// works fine!
```

However if you aren't on TS4.9^ or you get your data from some external source which types it as `ApexAxisChartSeries` you can check out the options below.

### `as` Assertion

[`as` assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions)

```js
// assuming some retrieveData function
const retrieveData = (): ApexAxisChartSeries => null! //implementation is not important

const data1 = retrieveData() as ApexAxisChartSeriesWithDataObject
data1[0]['data'][0]['x'] += 1
// works fine!
```

You have to be careful when doing something like this however, it is possible to still get TypeErrors if your assertion is wrong. If you are fully confident that you will always have data be an array of objects it may be wiser to instead modify the `retrieveData` function's return value instead (if it is within your control). If not you can wrap it in your own function which just returns the same value but has a different returnType.

```js
const retrieveDataCorrect = () => 
  retrieveData() as ApexAxisChartSeriesWithDataObject
```

### Type-guarding

[Type-guarding](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#typeof-type-guards) is the safest way to do this, if you can't be fully confident in the data's shape, you can just use if statements and TS will automatically narrow the type

```js
const data2 = retrieveData()
if (data2[0]['data'][0] && 
  !Array.isArray(data2[0]['data'][0])
  && typeof data2[0]['data'][0] == 'object'
) {
  data2[0]['data'][0]['x'] += 1
  // works fine!
}
```

You can also use your own defined [predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates)

```js
const satisfiesApexAxisChartSeriesWithDataObject = (data: ApexAxisChartSeries): 
  data is ApexAxisChartSeriesWithDataObject =>
{
  return (!!data2[0]['data'][0] && 
    !Array.isArray(data2[0]['data'][0])
    && typeof data2[0]['data'][0] == 'object'
  )
}
if (satisfiesApexAxisChartSeriesWithDataObject(data2)) {
  data2[0]['data'][0]['x'] += 1
  // works fine!
}
```

View all examples in action on [TS Playground](https://tsplay.dev/m336km)